# Removing items from unnamed lists in Python

Tags: python

Why doesn't the following statement return a list without `'item'` in Python?

```
list(something_convertible_to_list).remove('item')
```

?

I would like to use the construction above to avoid explicitly naming a list for the sole purpose of passing it to a function, i.e.:

```
operate_on_list(list(something_convertible_to_list).remove('item'))

def operate_on_list(my_list):
    # do_something
    print my_list
    return
```

Is this possible in Python?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In python, built-in methods which operate in place return `None` to make it **absolutely clear** that they mutated an object.

Of course, you're free to disregard this convention and write your own wrapper:

```
def my_remove(lst,what):
   lst.remove(what)
   return lst
```

But I wouldn't recommend it.

As a side note, if you want to do something like:

```
list(something_convertible_to_list).remove('item')
```

but get the list back, the following might be similar enough to be useful:

```
[x for x in something_iterable if x != 'item']
```

And this *does* return a list, but where `list.remove` only takes away 1 `'item'`, this will construct a new list with no `'item'` in it.

Comment: Thanks. That's very helpful. I presume that there are no other list built-ins that I can use for this purpose (i.e. that my only, easy alternative is to define my own list method). Is that right?

Comment: @Nicolas -- Thanks.  I was working toward that as you commented.  Great minds must think alike :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
my_list[:my_list.index('item')]+my_list[my_list.index('item')+1:]
```

although you do have two searches here.

or

```
[item for item in my_sequence if item != 'item']
```

The first one will remove the first `'item'` from the list, while the second one will remove every `'item'`.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that those two statements aren't equivalent in the case where you have multiple `'item'` in your list.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that to use your first answer, you need to have a list to begin with (or at least a sequence), and it needs to already be bound to a name in the local namespace -- Not just something that you can use to construct a list.

Comment: I think the `my_list` part pretty much explains that

Comment: Yeah, maybe I should have been more clear -- Part of this is also that the list must be already bound to a name in your local namespace, which is what OP is explicitly trying to avoid (although I don't know why that is a concern ...)

Comment: yeah, point taken. 4 casts is probably not the best way to do this :)
not to mention that it could be an iterator